# Python create numpy array with different dtypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I want to create a `numpy` array (size ~65000 rows x 17 columns). The first column contains complex numbers and the rest contains unsigned integers.

I first create a `numpy.zeros` array of the desired size and after that I want to fill it with complex numbers and uints as described above. I have looked at the `dtypes` option and therein should lie the solution I think, but I can't get it to work.

After that I want to save the whole array to a text file as CSV as follows:

0.25+0.30j,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

0.30+0.40j,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1

etc...

I tried this amongst others, but later it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and
>   'numpy.ndarray'

```
m = 16

dt = numpy.dtype([('comp', numpy.complex), ('f0', numpy.int64), ('f1', numpy.int64),
    ('f2', numpy.int64), ('f3', numpy.int64), ('f4', numpy.int64), ('f5', numpy.int64),
    ('f6', numpy.int64), ('f7', numpy.int64), ('f8', numpy.int64), ('f9', numpy.int64),
    ('f10', numpy.int64), ('f11', numpy.int64), ('f12', numpy.int64), ('f13', numpy.int64),
    ('f14', numpy.int64), ('f15', numpy.int64)])

fields = numpy.zeros((2**m, m+1), dtype=dt)

for i in range(0, m):
    fields[:,0] = fields[:,0] + 1 # for example I add only 1 here
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: The data type is now a "row" in itself, so you need only `fields = numpy.zeros(2**m, dtype=dt)`.

Comment: In the for loop it then gives me the following error: IndexError: too many indices

Comment: Your `fields` is now 2d, with 17 columns, and each element has 17 fields.  That's 17x bigger than what you probably want.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this does what you want:

**Edit:** Flattened the structure, so it is now closer to what you originally had in mind, and you can save it using `savetxt`.

```
import numpy

m = 15
rows = 5

integers = [('f'+str(i), numpy.int64) for i in range(m)]
dt = numpy.dtype([('comp', numpy.complex)] + integers)
fields = numpy.zeros(rows, dtype=dt)

fields['comp'] += 1j
fmt = '%s ' + m*' %u'
numpy.savetxt('fields.txt', fields, fmt=fmt)
```

Note: the array is now basically a vector of elements of the type `dt`. <s>You can access the complex number with `fields[row][0]`, and `fields[row][1]` will return the "subarray" of integers. That means to change a specific integer, you'll need to do something like this: `fields[row][1][5] = 7`.</s>

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the rows.  Vector operations work WITHIN each field: `fields['comp'] += 1j` and `fields['f']=np.arange(15)`

Comment: Is there a way of writing this dtype to a file (with `savetxt`) without the brackets?  `fmt='%f %s'` works but prints the `f` field as a list.

Comment: A `np.complex` field displayed with `%s` produces `(2+1j)`.  That's good if you like the `()`, but awkward if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

`np.savetxt` does not handle fields with different number of values very well.  A complex field has 2 values per row, an int just one.  Or 15 in Psirus's version.

The basic operation in `savetxt` is:

```
for row in X:
   fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

But the row `tuple` for your dtype is something like (for just 2 int fields)

```
In [306]: tuple(X[1])
Out[306]: ((1+4j), 0, 0)
```

And for Psirus's dtype:

```
In [307]: tuple(fields[1])
Out[307]: ((1+4j), array([2, 3], dtype=int64))
```

It's hard to come up with a format string that works without resorting to a generic `%s` for at least the complex value.  It is harder still to come up with one that passes `savetxt` error checking.

It may be best to write your own `save` routine, one that formats that tuple exactly as you want it.

The `savetxt` code is readily available to read and copy.  The `asbyte` business is for Python3 compatibility.

It might easier to skip the complex dtype, and work with a plain 2d array,  Here's a simple example of writing a complex 'field' plus a couple of ints, without resorting to a structured dtype.  The 'complex' magic resides in the `fmt` string.

```
In [320]: Y = np.zeros((5,4),dtype=int)
In [321]: Y[:,0]=np.arange(5)
In [322]: Y[:,1]=np.arange(5,0,-1)
In [323]: Y[:,2]=np.arange(5,0,-1)
In [324]: Y[:,3]=np.arange(10,15)

In [325]: Y
Out[325]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  5, 10],
       [ 1,  4,  4, 11],
       [ 2,  3,  3, 12],
       [ 3,  2,  2, 13],
       [ 4,  1,  1, 14]])

In [326]: np.savetxt('mypy/temp.txt',Y,fmt='%3d+%dj, %3d, %3d')

In [327]: cat mypy/temp.txt
  0+5j,   5,  10
  1+4j,   4,  11
  2+3j,   3,  12
  3+2j,   2,  13
  4+1j,   1,  14
```